# D3: Are "parabolic" scales possible?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm working on a chart for which each observation has a value between `[-100,100]`, and I want to plot each point's position on a scale. The challenge is that the vast majority of the points have values in one region of the scale (the distribution is essentially Gaussian with mean 0).

In the past, when I've needed to plot something like a Zipf probability density distribution, I've used log scales to spread out the points in the congested region. Now my situation is similar, except that I have two distributions for which I need to spread out the points (the positive scale from `[0, max]` and the mirrored negative scale from `[0, min]`).

I know I could create one scale for positive values and one for negative values, but I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve this layout with only one scale. It seems that something like a parabolic scale could help out here (if that exists). Is it possible to achieve something like this in D3?

Comment: `I've used log scales to spread out the points in congested region` I'd like to hear more about this because at first glance, this sounds like you're skewing your chart, which leads to misinterpretation of the data.

Comment: @vol7ron Log scales  are not so rare--it's just important to show users the log scale so they understand the distribution/data. Here's an example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5537697

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with that time one, but a quick google shut me up.  I can see practical examples, especially for higher level math.  Other examples including map charts, with logarithmic density shadings seemed more appropriate.

Comment: Did the scaleLog not work(https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleLog)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before explaining my proposed solution, some considerations about the comments in this question: you **cannot** use a log scale in your situation. This is an easy mathematical principle: Log(0) is minus infinity. Actually, this is explicitly stated in the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#log-scales):

> As log(0) = -∞, a log scale domain must be strictly-positive or strictly-negative; the domain must not include or cross zero.

That being said, let's go to the proposed solution.

You could create your own scale (it's not that complicated). However, here, I'll use a [interpolate](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_interpolate) function, based on this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541780/creating-an-asinh-inverse-hyperbolic-sine-scale-in-d3-js-v4/40702243#40702243) (not a duplicate, though, because you want the opposite) and this [code from Mike Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/56ea94205411ee9e4dbec3742f7ad08c).

Using a linear scale, we set an interpolator:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-100, 100])
    .interpolate(easeInterpolate(d3.easeQuadInOut));
```

Then, we use an [easing](https://github.com/d3/d3-ease) in the `easeInterpolate` function:

```
function easeInterpolate(ease) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var i = d3.interpolate(a, b);
        return function(t) {
            return i(ease(t));
        };
    };
}
```

Here I'm using `d3.easeQuadInOut`, which I think suits you, but you can change this for another one, or even creating your own.

Have a look at this demo. I'm creating 50 circles, evenly spaced from -100 to +100 (-100, -96, -92, -88... until +100). You can see that they are *moved away* from the center. If you use this scale with your data, you'll avoid the crowded data points around zero:

```js
var data = d3.range(51).map(function(d) {
  return -100 + (d * 4)
});

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 100);

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-100, 100])
  .range([20, 580])
  .interpolate(easeInterpolate(d3.easeQuadInOut));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,70)")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScale(d)
  })
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("fill", "teal")

function easeInterpolate(ease) {
  return function(a, b) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(a, b);
    return function(t) {
      return i(ease(t));
    };
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

In case you ask, that last tick is not `80100`. That's just the `80` tick overlapping with the `100` tick (the same thing happens with the `-80` and the `-100`).

Also, it is worth noting that there is nothing wrong in using transformed scales, and that even if it does *deform* or *skew* the chart, it's perfect valid and does not lead to misinterpretations, **as long as you inform the users** about the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I haven't had the need to do any advanced charting in recent years. Mostly simple data visualization that could use C3 (simplified D3) or Highcharts. I'm sure I'll be revisiting this question and answer in the years to come.